# How to Transform a Line to another Line which is parallel to it

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Let say i have two parallel lines, $L_1$ and $L_2$,

[image]

Now how to Transform line $L_2$ in to $L_1$.

Comment: What do you mean by transform? If you mean two lines (not segments) on a plane, you could use two symmetries, to just translate it. Even single symmetry would do if you don't care about the sign.

Comment: I mean two line segments. I need to transform L2 into L1. Means, L2 and L1 become same lines.

Comment: If the two segments are of the same length, you just translate, no?

Comment: @J.M., yes u are right

Comment: @dtldarek, can you explain a little more.

Comment: @user960567 The comment was too short, see below ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transform point $(x1,y1)$ to $(x2,y2)$, and $(x3,y3)$ to $(x4,y4)$. This means:
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) \cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x1 \\ y1 \end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x2 \\ y2 \end{array} \right) $$
And:
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) \cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x3 \\ y3 \end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x4 \\ y4 \end{array} \right) $$

You have four equations in the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$. Once you solve these equations the transformed coordinates $(x',y')$ are related to the old ones by:
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) \cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{c} x' \\ y' \end{array} \right) $$

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I think some of those $c$s were meant to be $d$s, nbubis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Thanks, Fixed.

Comment: @user960567 - Do you want to explain what you don't understand? Are you familiar with matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yup. I am thinking, X2 + (X1 - X2), Y2 + (Y1 - Y2) may work or not

Comment: nbubis, @GerryMyerson Yup. I am thinking simple subtraction may work or not. Because the difference between, X1,Y1 - X2,Y2 and X3,Y3 - X4,Y4 is same

Comment: You mean the lines are of equal length? then yes, subtraction will work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are too short, so I will explain it here. Let $A = (X_1, Y_1)$, $B = (X_2, Y_2)$, $C = (X_3, Y_3)$ and $D = (X_4, Y_4)$. We have that $AC\ \|\ BD$ and that you want to transform $A$ to $B$ and $C$ to $D$ (of course the same approach can be used to map $A$ to $D$ and $C$ to $B$). The notation $|PQ|$ means the length of $PQ$.

First of all, there are infinitely many transformations that would map $AC$ to $BD$ (without any constraints, if you assume that you want your map to be of some specific class, there may be just a few or even none), and I will just give you an example of such transformation.

What I will construct is called usually [homothety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) or simply scaling, and this is one of the basic geometry transformations (along with rotation, translation and symmetry).

To start we need the [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_center), let call it $S = (S_x, S_y)$. However, we know that $S$ is a point on the line passing through $A$ and $B$, and also on the line passing through $C$ and $D$. Therefore, $S$ is the intersection of those two lines (with the special case I will deal later). To apply the transformation to the point say $P$, just draw a line $SP$ and then set $P'$ on the same line, but with $|SP'| = \frac{|BS|}{|AS|}|SP| = \frac{|DS|}{|CS|}|SP|$ (where positive sign means $X'$ is on the same side as $X$, and the negative sign denotes opposite side). Please, compare it with [Intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) (in my country this is known as Thales' theorem). To give algebraic formula:
$$T(P) = \frac{|BS|}{|AS|}(P-S) + S$$
or written more explicitly:
$$T(P_x, P_y) = \left(\frac{|BS|}{|AS|}(P_x-S_x)+S_x, \frac{|BS|}{|AS|}(P_y-S_y)+S_y\right)$$

As you can see, if $S = (0,0)$ then this becomes a simple scaling. There is a special case when $AB\ \|\ CD$, i.e. when $S$ does not exists, or as some like to say $S$ is in infinity. But in this degenerate case homothety becomes just translation, so $$T(P) = P+AB$$ or $$T(P_x, P_y) = (P_x + B_x - A_x, P_y + B_y - A_y)$$

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: Isn't this is some how complex. What about taking the difference? I mean subtraction

Comment: @user960567 What do you mean?

Comment: See below comments.